# How to attach a PDF generated using react-pdf package to an email as attachment using sendGrid

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, react-pdf

Is there any way I can send the generated PDF using react-pdf package as an attachment to an email using sendGrid in nodejs? I am generating a pdf from my component and I want it to be sent in an email. Has anyone did this before?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?